# Does Boost.Serialization serialize differently on different platforms?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization, boost-iostreams

I use Boost.Serialization to serialize a std::map. The code looks like this

```
void Dictionary::serialize(std::string & buffer)
{
  try {
    std::stringstream ss;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive archive(ss);
    archive << dict_; 
    buffer = ss.str();
  } catch (const std::exception & ex) {
    throw DictionaryException(ex.what());
  }
}

void Dictionary::deserialize(const char * const data, int length)
{
  try {
    namespace io = boost::iostreams;
    io::array_source source(data, length);
    io::stream<io::array_source> in(source);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive archive(in);
    archive >> dict_;
  } catch (const std::exception & ex) {
    throw DictionaryException(ex.what());
  }
}
```

I compiled and tested the code on a Mac Snow Leopard and on Ubuntu Lucid 10.04. There is Boost 1.40 on both systems. On the Mac I built the code myself. On the Ubuntu box I got the binaries via aptitude.

Problem: When I serialize the map on the Mac I can't deserialize it on the Ubuntu box. I get an **invalid signature** exception if I try.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try using a `text_iarchive` and `text_oarchive` instead of binary archives. From the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html)

> In this tutorial, we have used a
>   particular archive class -
>   text_oarchive for saving and
>   text_iarchive for loading. text
>   archives render data as text and are
>   portable across platforms. In addition
>   to text archives, the library includes
>   archive class for native binary data
>   and xml formatted data. Interfaces to
>   all archive classes are all identical.
>   Once serialization has been defined
>   for a class, that class can be
>   serialized to any type of archive.

Comment: Note that this might have a very significant effect on your application's performance.

Answer (score 9):

boost:archive::binary_xarchive are currently not portable

With my interpretation that means that there can be differences on different platforms. The text archives gives you the same input/output behaviour on all systems. 
Also there is a related TODO entry which tries to solve the portability issue of the binary archives: [TODO Entry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/todo.html#portablebinaryarchive)

Answer (score 7):

The performance with text_archives is magnitudes slower than binary_archive. If performance is your thing, you may try out [an unofficial portable binary archive](http://www.boostpro.com/vault/index.php?direction=0&order=&directory=serialization) `eos_portable_archive`. I've used it to serialize data across 32 bit and 64 bit on Windows with success. You may give it a go.

Just need to put the files in your serialization directory. The files there are not up to date with the latest boost version (1.44.0) but you just need to make 2 very trivial adjustments to make it work (your compiler will tell you with very obvious error message).

Comment: `eos_portable_archive` doesn't support serializing wstrings, which for me broke the deal. There is a portable_binary_iarchive.hpp that comes with boost (in the boost/libs/serialization/example) which doesn't have this limitation, and worked fine for me. It has some other limitations [documented here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/todo.html#portablebinaryarchives)

Comment: @Omer Raviv: The portable archive doesn't support serializing floating point types, which was broken deal for me at that point. In fact I realized that `boost::serialization` [adds horrendous size](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2010/09/63015.php) to the executable that I abandoned it and rolled my own. I am not sure if newer versions of boost have fixed that.

Comment: **UPDATE:** EOS portable archive v5.0 now [supports wstring](http://epa.codeplex.com/releases/view/91073) as well. New home is [here](http://epa.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the answers, but wanted to add a clarifying note. You might think this is an annoying oversight, but in fact coming up with and implementing a portable binary format is not such a trivial task. The only standard that I'm aware of that effectively tackles the problem *in binary* is [ASN.1](http://www.asn1.org/books/index.htm).

XML pruports to tackle the same problem, but generally does it in text. There's a piggyback standard for XML called [Fast Infoset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Infoset) that allows XML to encode the data in binary form instead, but it uses ASN.1.

Comment: Wow. Not sure I've ever heard "effectively" and "ASN.1" so close together before. But then, I did once have to debug an ASN.1 parser that someone else had written, so I tend to associate it with hours of excruciating agony. May not actually be ASN.1's fault.

Comment: I don't argue. It's my fault. I should've read the Boost.Serialization docs. Text is just fine.

Comment: @Steve Jessop - Not your fault at all, but I think its mostly the task's fault. There are probably some general ASN.1 parsers out there, but every one I have ever seen just parses the subset of ASN.1 that it expects out of whoever the other side is. Even that is a hairy task.

Comment: no doubt this was the case for the parser I was debugging. It was only being used for X.509 certificates and related entities.