# Serializing binary data in boost fails with `invalid signature' error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-serialization

I'm having difficulties figuring out correct way of using boost serialization/asio to send objects over network. The `message` class is as simple as possible. It's not C++ friendly nor suitable for my needs, I just keep it simple temporarily to test asio/ser:

```
class message {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
public:
    message(){}
    int type;
    int sender;
    int assignment;
    int nogood;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & type;
        ar & sender;
        ar & assignment;
        ar & nogood;
    }
};
```

On the client side when agent decides to send a message, sends it to server over it's tcp connection:

```
message m;
// do something to generate message
boost::asio::streambuf bufx;
std::ostream os( &bufx );
boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar( os );
ar & m;
boost::asio::write( socket, bufx);
```

Server side code:

```
boost::asio::streambuf bufx;
std::istream is(&bufx);
boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(is);  // <--- Exception: invalid signature
size_t rcx = asio::read(socket,bufx);
message m;
ia >> m;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server-side code, your `streambuf` is empty when you create the binary archive.  If the archive constructor is looking for a magic number at the beginning of the archive then it won't find it.  Try filling the `streambuf` with the call to `boost::asio::read()` **before** constructing the stream and archive.

Comment: Tanks for your answer. I moved `read()` immediately after `streambuf` definition. Now read throws an exception with this message: `End of file`

Comment: I believe that is expected.  `read()` blocks until the buffer is full or an error occurs.  In this case the "error" is that the socket has closed.  You may wish to use the `read()` [overload](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload6.html) that returns status via a `boost::system::error_code` reference argument instead of throwing on error.

Answer (score 2):

I got same exception.

And [This official example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf.html#boost_asio.reference.basic_streambuf.examples) helps me.

If you are still in trouble, try this.

```
size_t n = sock.receive(bufs);

// received data is "committed" from output sequence to input sequence
b.commit(n);

std::istream is(&b);
std::string s;
is >> s;
```

In my case, I use async_read. Actually, I modified the [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/serialization/connection.hpp).

```
  boost::asio::streambuf inbound_;
  boost::asio::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type bufs = inbound_.prepare(inbound_data_size);
  void (connection::*f)(
      const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t,
      T&, boost::tuple<Handler>)
    = &connection::handle_read_data<T, Handler>;
  boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(bufs), 
    boost::bind(f, this,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, boost::ref(t), handler));
```

And then at the handler

```
  /// Handle a completed read of message data.
  template <typename T, typename Handler>
  void handle_read_data(const boost::system::error_code& e, std::size_t bytes_transferred,
      T& t, boost::tuple<Handler> handler)
  {
    if (e)
    {
      boost::get<0>(handler)(e);
    }
    else
    {
      // Extract the data structure from the data just received.
      try
      {
        inbound_.commit(bytes_transferred);
        std::istream archive_stream(&inbound_);
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive archive(archive_stream);
        archive >> t;
      }
      catch (std::exception& err)
      {
        // Unable to decode data.
        boost::system::error_code error(boost::asio::error::invalid_argument);
        boost::get<0>(handler)(error);
        return;
      }

      // Inform caller that data has been received ok.
      boost::get<0>(handler)(e);
    }
  }
```